# Hows my code in terms of Code Efficiency

Tags: vb.net, dynamic

I'm writing a game, and all my code works, however I'm looking for more efficient methods of writing my code.

Is there a more efficient way to write this particular piece of code

```
 Select Case (N)
                        Case 1
                            If Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger > 0 Or Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger > 0 Or (Player1HandGroup(16).QuantityInteger > 0 And (IDbuster = 8 Or IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                                                          IDbuster = 10 Or IDbuster = 11)) Then
                                DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.ShowDialog()
                                If DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Or DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                                    DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.PlayerTemp = T
                                End If

                            End If
                        Case 2
                            If Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger2 > 0 Or Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger2 > 0 Or (Player1HandGroup(16).QuantityInteger2 > 0 And (IDbuster = 8 Or IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                                                          IDbuster = 10 Or IDbuster = 11)) Then
                                DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.ShowDialog()
                                If DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Or DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                                    DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.PlayerTemp = T
                                End If
                            End If
                        Case 3
                            If Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger3 > 0 Or Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger3 > 0 Or (Player1HandGroup(16).QuantityInteger3 > 0 And (IDbuster = 8 Or IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                                                          IDbuster = 10 Or IDbuster = 11)) Then
                                DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.ShowDialog()
                                If DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Or DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                                    DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.PlayerTemp = T
                                End If
                            End If
                        Case 4
                            If Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger4 > 0 Or Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger4 > 0 Or (Player1HandGroup(16).QuantityInteger4 > 0 And (IDbuster = 8 Or IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                                                          IDbuster = 10 Or IDbuster = 11)) Then
                                DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.ShowDialog()
                                If DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Or DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                                    DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.PlayerTemp = T
                                End If
                            End If
                        Case 5
                            If Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger5 > 0 Or Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger5 > 0 Or (Player1HandGroup(16).QuantityInteger5 > 0 And (IDbuster = 8 Or IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                                                          IDbuster = 10 Or IDbuster = 11)) Then
                                DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.ShowDialog()
                                If DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Or DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                                    DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.PlayerTemp = T
                                End If
                            End If
                    End Select
```

The only difference between each case is:
 N represents which player is chosen, then with the particular number of N I decide which Quantity integer in my Structure group to look at.

If there were a way to somehow reduce it to just 1 instance and add the "number" on the quantity integer dynamically, I feel it would really free up a lot of my code allthroughout my project.

Comment: `Hows my code in terms of Code Efficiency` - In terms of efficiency I don't know, but in terms of cleanliness, it's actually zero.

Comment: How so? (or are you talking about how clear my post title is...?)

Comment: Belongs at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GakkonoAto first of all, your code is all duplicated, just with different integer values, you should remove the `select case` and create a reusable logic. Second, You're using `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult` and you should add an `Imports` statement to import the full `System.Windows.Forms` namespace instead of fully typing it every time

Comment: Time to play random stack-site roulette. Time to post this on codereview.stackexchange.com and have a similar post forwarding me to yet another stack website.

Comment: Well that was my question HighCore. How can I reuse this particular piece of code?

Comment: Have you got actual measurements telling you the performance isn't good enough, and this is the bottleneck? Otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what type `Player1HandGroup(14)` is, but I am mostly positive that it's of the same type as `Player1HandGroup(17)` and `Player1HandGroup(16)`. So you could have a `Sub` that takes a parameter of type `Function(of YourTypeOfPlayer1HandGroup)`, and then pass `function(x) x.QuantityInteger` into it, and so on.

```
IDbuster = 8 Or IDbuster = 9 Or IDbuster = 10 Or IDbuster = 11
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
{8,9,10,11}.Contains(IDbuster)
```

So your code would turn to something like this:

```
Select Case N
  Case 1: DoProcessingWithProperty(Function(x) x.QuantityInteger)
  Case 2: DoProcessingWithProperty(Function(x) x.QuantityInteger2)
  Case 3: DoProcessingWithProperty(Function(x) x.QuantityInteger3)
  Case 4: DoProcessingWithProperty(Function(x) x.QuantityInteger4)
  Case 5: DoProcessingWithProperty(Function(x) x.QuantityInteger5)
End Select
```

Where

```
Sub DoProcessingWithProperty(f As Func(Of YourTypeOfPlayer1HandGroup))
  If f(Player1HandGroup(14)) > 0 Or f(Player1HandGroup(17)) > 0 Or _
    (f(Player1HandGroup(16)) > 0 And {8,9,10,11}.Contains(IDbuster)) Then
    DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.ShowDialog()
    If DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult=Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Or _
       DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.DialogResult=Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
      DodgeBlockDisarmDialog.PlayerTemp = T
    End If
  End If      
End Sub
```

This is a very generic refactoring (minimum impact), and it may not be the best way to refactor in your current situation, but it certainly makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your current data structrue doesn't support healthy practices.

If you have N items of the same type in the same class:

```
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger2
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger3
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger4
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger5
```

You should create a `List(Of T)` to hold that:

```
public class HandGroup

    Public Property QuantityInteger As List(Of Integer)
    ...Etc...
End Class

Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger(0)
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger(1)
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger(2)
...etc
```

That way you could do something like:

```
if Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger(N)   ... etc etc etc
```

Comment: Public Property QuantityInteger As List(Of Integer)

Comment: So will Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger(N) after using the list(of t) function be the same as Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger1                        


Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger2
                     
Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger3


etc?

Comment: Will this even still be part of my structure group? You called it "Public class HandGroup"?

Comment: @GakkonoAto I don't know dude, it's just to give you an idea that you need to replace the `QuantityInteger1, QuantityInteger2, QuantityInteger3` properties for the `List(of Integer)`.